Dask concat issue with DataFrames of different lengths, pandas works fine
I’m trying to use dask to read at least 12 files with approx. 700 MB, each. The files were created on the same way, with only one column and with exactly the same number of lines (about 43 million lines). Then I want to concatenate the dataframes by axis=1 to a single one, from which I can create another mean dataframe again by axis=1. When I then try to compute the new dataframe I get the “ValueError: Concatenated DataFrames of different lengths”. However, when I do this with pandas everything works fine.
First, I thought the files were different for any reason, so I checked the number of lines, number of columns, datatype, but I couldn’t find any differences. The files were written by Tecplot360 with the same setting, so I don’t know how anything could be different.
Then I started using repartition(npartitions=100) and reset_index(drop=True) which I found in another post, dealing with another Concatenated error – this didn’t help, both combined, each one without the other nor with several different npartitions. I created new files on my own (with only 5000 lines in the column), in this case it worked with dask, so maybe the original files are to different. But then I tried it with pandas and it worked. If there were differences in the files, concatenate shouldn’t work in pandas, right?
Since it works with pandas of course I could use pandas but it takes way more time than using dask.
Example:
The files have 7 header lines, which I can't avoid, in line 8 the data begins and has in total 43,614,208 lines with only one column. There is 1 space in front of each value but none the the end.
 -2.5000000E-04
 0.000000E+00
 1.500000E-02
 -7.300000E-05
...

Here is the latest code I used with dask:
import dask.dataframe as da

file_paths = ['file_1.txt', 'file_2.txt']

ddf_file1 = da.read_csv(file_paths[0], skiprows=7, header=None, sep='\\s+')
ddf_file2 = da.read_csv(file_paths[1], skiprows=7, header=None, sep='\\s+')

ddf_f1 = ddf_file1.repartition(npartitions=100).reset_index(drop=True)
ddf_f2 = ddf_file2.repartition(npartitions=100).reset_index(drop=True)

combined_ddf = da.concat([ddf_f1, ddf_f2], axis=1)

mean_ddf = combined_ddf.mean(axis=1)

ddf = combined_ddf.compute()


The lastest (and only) pandas code version:
import pandas as pd

file_paths = ['file_1.txt', 'file_2.txt']

pdf_file1 = pd.read_csv(file_paths[0], skiprows=7, header=None, sep='\\s+')
pdf_file2 = pd.read_csv(file_paths[1], skiprows=7, header=None, sep='\\s+')

combined_pdf = pd.concat([pdf_file1, pdf_file2], axis=1)

df_pd_mean = combined_pdf.mean(axis=1)

python version: 3.13,
dask version: 2024.10.0 and 2024.11.1,
dask-expr version: 1.1.18 and 1.1.16
Edit:
I found this in the dask documentary:

It should also be noted that this function may fail if a CSV file includes quoted strings that contain the line terminator. To get around this you can specify blocksize=None to not split files into multiple partitions, at the cost of reduced parallelism.

I tried it and the ValueError is gone, however now the calculation is even slower than pandas.

I guess the problem comes from the fact that partitions size are computed according to number of bytes, which probably doesn't mean the same number of records per partitions. Maybe try to repartition using divisions kwarg.
